# How are request parameters converted in Spring Data Rest

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have a repository for a mapped class in Spring Data Rest. The mapped class has an enum field:

```
@Entity
class Run {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Integer id

    Status status

    public static enum Status {
        IN_PROCESS('inProcess'),
        FAILED('failed'),
        SUCCESS('success')

        String value

        Status(String value) {
            this.value = value
        }

        @JsonValue
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return value
        }
    }
}
```

I have declared the following repository for the Run entity:

```
interface RunRepository extends CrudRepository<Run, Integer> {

    public Iterable<Run> findByStatus(@Param('status') Run.Status status)

}
```

I've implemented a custom Converter for the Run.Status enum, which I've for the sake of simplicity, cut down to the following:

```
class RunStatusConverter implements Converter<String, Run.Status> {

    @Override
    Run.Status convert(String s) {
        return Run.Status.IN_PROCESS
    }
}
```

This converter has been registered using a `@Configuration` annotated class, and it works fine when used to convert custom `@Controller` method parameters, such as in the following:

```
@Controller
class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(path = '/test-status')
    public @ResponseBody String testStatus(@RequestParam Run.Status status) {
        println 'status: ' + status
        return status.value
    }

}
```

When, however, I call the `findByStatus` method (over HTTP) on the `RunRepository` class, the converter does not get called and instead I get a `org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException` whose underlying cause is the following: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant Run.Status.inProcess`.

It seems the custom converter is not getting called when passing parameters to the repository.

How do I get the repository to receive the correctly converted request parameter, when calling exposed repository methods over HTTP?

Comment: Is it necessary to receive the `@Param('status')` as `inProcess` and not as `IN_PROCESS`?

Comment: @Patrick It is. The camel case string is the general representation of these in the system. Also there are many other cases with exactly the same problem. I just chose this one because it was fairly simple to demonstrate.